# How to deserialize wrapped json array in asp.net through web request?

Tags: c#, web-services

```
{"lstCitiesResult":[{"city_id":"21","city_name":"Trichy"},  
                    {"city_id":"22","city_name":"Chennai"},
                    {"city_id":"24","city_name":"Mumbai"},  
                    {"city_id":"25","city_name":"Hyderabad"}] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) to deserialize your json string. Define you own class:

```
public class City 
{
   public int City_id { get; set; }
   public string City_name { get; set; }
}

public class YourModel
{
    public City[] lstCitiesResult { get; set; }
}
```

So you can call:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(jsonString);
```